# how do you say "Refugees are humans too" in Japanese

Tags: words, phrases

how do you say "Refugees are humans too" in Japanese

Would it be なんみんも　にんげんです。

*(My Kanji is quite limited, so that's why I've written it in Hiragana)*

Comment: In what context? Are you (speaking/writing/tweeting etc.) to (children/friends/boss/the public etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  You can say:

「なんみんもにんげん（だ/です/である）。」 or

「なんみんも**また**にんげん（だ/です/である）。」

Comment: what's the difference between the two terms? i.e. what effects does また　have?

Comment: ^ Dania, また adds emphasis on the 「も」"too/also/as well", and probably has a nuance of "equally"... and I think ～もまたにんげんだ sounds a bit more formal/literary than ～もにんげんだ